# limit in subquery not allowed in MySQL but I need "it"

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

First the SQL =

```
delete 
  from eat_history 
 where food in 
    ( select food 
        from eat_history 
      where name ='minicake' 
       and cream='yes' 
     order 
        by eat_time desc 
      limit 1
    ) t1
```

My intention is to remove the **latest** eaten food whose name is 'minicake' and cream='yes' (there could be multiple items). MySQL doesn't allow it as I point out in title. However, in my case, the "**limit 1**" is the crucial point. Is there a good workaround, best is a single SQL statement?

=====

EDIT: I find an answer in another question that though MySQL doesn't allow limit in IN clause but it's allowed in sub subquery, e.g. add a "select * from" outside originally "select food..." can work around the restriction. Seriously, I don't know why but I test it, it's ok.

Comment: You  don't need a sub-query here. Move the where and limit clauses to the main query.

Comment: It sounds like cheating. You ate the cake. At least own up to it.

Answer (score 2):

Firts you should remove t1  after the in clause

```
  delete from eat_history where food in (
      select food from eat_history where name='minicake' and cream='yes' 
      order by eat_time DESC  limit 1
      )
```

but you could avoid the limit using a group by an join

```
  delete from eat_history  e 
  inner join  (
      select food, max(eat_time)  max_time
      from eat_history 
      where name='minicake' and cream='yes' 
      group by foo
 ) t on t.food = e.food and t.max_time = e.eat_time
```

Comment: in the earlier query you posted, you skipped the order mode DESC/ASC

Comment: @Dickson  in the first the order by is the same as the OP  and in the second  is select just one record and don't need  the order by

Comment: I agree, however, the first query, without the sorting order, MySQL will sort in ascending order, so instead of picking the last record, it will pick the first and then will be deleting the first record instead of the last/most recent record. Seen you corrected it. Cheers man

Comment: @Dickson   .. correct  .. answer  updated .. good  point  .. upvoted somewhere  .. thanks

Comment: @scaisEdge First sorry for missing "desc", I've modified the question. Second, as I point out in title, your first SQL will also get "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
" error. I've found an answer in another question which solves this problem (I'll write it under question). However, Your second SQL is another way to workaround it. Thanks for you answer and I will vote it.